# Database Migration from legacy app on old iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, database

I recently replaced my old iPad 2 (2011 - iOS 9) with a new iPad 10,2" (iOS 14). I personally made the migration between the two iPad and everything worked quite well.

Everything but ONE APP. This app, called Anamnesis, reported "*the app is not compatible with this iOS version*". I wrote to the app developer ([www.fuze.cc](http://www.fuze.cc)) which is not answering. I wrote to each member of the Fuze team and only one answered me (Icaro) who is no more working on Fuze, unfortunately.

I'm quite desperated because I strongly need this app to work: I use Anamnesis to register each patient I see everyday. I have about 1000 records in that Anamnesis database, which is stored locally in the old iPad.

There's no option in Anamnesis to export the database into a new one. There's no option to migrate it with a cloud service. I don't know what to do to make use of that database into the new iPad or to transfer that data into a new database which I can use into an app compatible with the new iPad.

I'm writing an webapp with Zoho Creator, so one day that I will have the database I can slightly control the migration. But actually, I don't know what to do.

This is a screenshot of Anamnesis taken in the old iPad:

[image]

Comment: No it is up to the developers to alter their program to run on new hardware. If "There's no option in Anamnesis to export the database into a new one." I would get all the data manually copied immediately. Your old iPad might break - the developer might go bust etc. I would not use any software that does not allow extraction of data for any purpose where you can't just throw the data away and the extraction has been shown to work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is completely irresponsible to store patient records without regards for security, backups and vendor support, and without being aware of the fact that the vendor discontinued the product and removed it from the App Store years ago. In many countries you would risk being fined heavily by the authorities.

At this point, you have a few options:

1. Contact the vendor offering money to have them help you migrate the data.
2. Contract a third party developer or IT-professional that can help you migrate the data (you could be 'lucky' that the data is simply stored in a SQLite database on device)
3. Migrate the data manually

I would strongly suggest initiating option 3 immediately while simualtenously pursuing the first two options.

Migrating the data manually could be done by simply going through all data in the app and taking screenshots along the way. Make sure to handle those screenshots in a professional and ethical manner - i.e. ensure they're not synced with Dropbox or Google Photos or something like that - and transfer them to a secure PC, where you can transfer the data into a new patient records system.